# Salesforce Omni-Studio Error : This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. [Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'jsonData')]

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, omnistudio

The below error in the picture was coming when you tried to use Nested Lookup inside Edit Block on Omni-Script or Using Block with repeat enabled.

You have to upgrade your Omni Script to the latest version.
https://volt.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/o0000000IKm8/a/3m000000xPM5/Tcei4lMX.Xeu0C49EUITfUfhsILDwb2JEIB6GQLBzws

[image: Omni-Studio Edit Block Error]